# Grep No such file or directory Error In Bash Script, Should I Insert Wait Command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I am running a script that has been working fine. However, yesterday, I got a couple errors. **These errors are after several loops of the script:**

```
sed: cant read file3.txt: No such file or directory
grep: file3.txt: No such file or directory
grep: file3.txt: No such file or directory
sed: cant read file3.txt: No such file or directory
grep: file3.txt: No such file or directory
```

Keep in mind, these errors do not happen consistently. It's occurring once in a while somewhere near this part of the script. **File3.txt is the file not being found:**

```
cat file1.txt | while read LINE; do grep -m 1 $LINE file2.txt >> file3.txt; done
sed -i 's/string//g'  file3.txt
grep 'string' file3.txt | cut -d '|' -f1-2 > file4.txt
grep -v 'string' file3.txt | cut -d '|' -f1-2 >> file5.txt
sed -i 's/string//' file3.txt
grep -Fvf file3.txt file1.txt > file6.txt
```

Now, I'm thinking that since file3.txt is being appended, or later operated on by SED, sometimes the next command starts too soon and it can't find the file? Should I put a wait command in between?

I have looked up many pages with this error, but was unable to find anything:

- [cat file_name | grep "something" results "cat: grep: No such file or directory" in shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624227/cat-file-name-grep-something-results-cat-grep-no-such-file-or-directory)
- [Pipe multiple commands to a single command with no EOF signal wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195285/pipe-multiple-commands-to-a-single-command-with-no-eof-signal-wait)
- [grep command works in command line, but not in bash script: get no such file or directory erro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173389/grep-command-works-in-command-line-but-not-in-bash-script-get-no-such-file-or)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/169539/sed-cant-find-a-file-that-obviously-exists
- ["No such file or directory" but it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949161/no-such-file-or-directory-but-it-exists)

If you think that putting a wait or sleep command will help, please let me know. Or, if you think there's a better solution, that would be great too. I'm running on Cygwin terminal. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you intend to have a blank in the file name from the first 'sed'?

Comment: You said this script gets run repeatedly. Does file3.txt get deleted between runs? Is is possible for the two runs to be concurrent? I am wondering about the 'sed -i'.

Comment: Whenever I see a whole bunch of temporary files, with multiple usages of grep and sed, I think of awk. I don't know why what you've got isn't working but I am almost certain that what you're trying to do can be reduced to a single awk script. If you show us your input and your desired output, then we can help you more effectively.

Comment: If `file1.txt` is ever empty then `file3.txt` won't be created.

Comment: I would not think a wait or sleep would help. The commands should not "start too soon". I would look for something in file1.txt that should be escaped when inserted into the grep command as $LINE. I think your file3.txt is not being created due to a quote or a semicolon or something.

Comment: @phreed, Yes, file3.txt gets `rm -f` right before the first command shown here, I can add it but don't think it would make a difference. Secondly, they are not running concurrently or in parallel.

Comment: @TomFenech, You're probably right. However, we need the output files for various uses so it has to be broken up that way. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @ccarton, `file1.txt` would not be empty. However, that would be a good catch. I think we're on the right track.

Comment: How do you get 4 grep errors trying to read file3.txt but only 3 greps in your script?

Comment: @ccarton that's a good point. Note that if the redirection was moved out of the loop `done >> file3.txt` (or possibly just `>`, depending on the context), this wouldn't happen.

Comment: @bmb, thanks for answering my initial question. I think this would make sense, if something is in `file1.txt` that needs to be escaped, then it could caused `file3.txt` not be generated. Would changing the quoting or bracket of $LINE to "{$LINE}" help that? The only character that is special in `file1.txt` is a dash `-`.

Comment: Wait a second, @ccarton, I think you nailed it. I'm looking at previous jobs, maybe it didn't happen multiple times. It could have happened just once. And the errors was only from one job. I think you solved it!

Comment: Glad I could help. bmb's observation should also be addressed even if it's not causing problems now. I think it should probably say `grep -F -m1 "$LINE" ...`

Comment: Thanks, will do change that as well. If you would like to provide an answer post, I will select it as correct and upvote :-) Please do the same :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If file1.txt is ever empty then file3.txt won't be created.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of redirecting to `file3.txt` inside the `while` loop, redirect the whole loop. Then the file will be created even if the loop never runs because the input file is empty.

```
while read LINE; do 
    grep -m 1 $LINE file2.txt
done < file1.txt > file3.txt
```

Comment: Hey Barmar, good point, that would help solve the issue as well. Thanks for the answer. Hope you liked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Also `do grep -m 1 $LINE file2.txt` will cause problems if there are crucial characters (space is the easiest of them).
Let's assume that the `$LINE` variable contains more than one word separated by spaces: `hello world`.
Now the command looks like this: `grep -m 1 hello world file2.txt` -  grep interpretation will look something like this: let's find all `hello` in file named `world` and file named `file2.txt` in current folder.

Using `"$LINE"` instead of `$LINE` will lead you to a whole different scenario.
Look at the difference between the following two:

```
grep -m 1 $LINE file2.txt
grep -m 1 "$LINE" file2.txt
```